# Pptx: How to convert chart axes to logarithmic?

Tags: python, visualization, python-pptx

I have prepared a column stack chart in pptx, but now I want to convert the Y-axis to logarithmic with the base 10 (similar option as we have in Powerpoint and excel). Is there any way, we can do it in pptx?

I could see something mentioned in XML specimen for logBase. The link is given below:

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-axes.html?highlight=logbase

But, not sure how to convert it!

Any help here would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like that attribute is not implemented yet, so you would need to manipulate the underlying XML directly. If you search on `python-pptx workaround function` you'll find some examples of doing that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried searching as per your suggestion, but didn't really understand how to do it. Can you help me here with some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_log_base(value_axis, base):
    # Inspired by:
    # https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/349#issuecomment-631261279
    # All it does is find a specific block to set the log base
    # and then modifies it to add the logBase block.
    scaling_elements = value_axis._element.xpath(r"c:scaling")
    if scaling_elements:
        scaling_element = scaling_elements[0]
    else:
        scaling_element = OxmlElement(r"c:scaling")
        value_axis._element.append(scaling_element)
    # now look for the target
    log_elements = scaling_element.xpath(r"c:logBase")
    if log_elements:
        log_element = log_elements[0]
        log_element.set("val", base)
    else:
        log_element = OxmlElement(r"c:logBase")
        log_element.set("val", base)
        value_axis._element.xpath(r"c:scaling")[0].append(log_element)
```

If it helps.